# How to set csrf token and name in codeIgniter and send it to angularjs function

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I have written code in view as

```
<input type="hidden" name="cna" id="cna" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cha" id="cha" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
```

Now how to get these fields in angularjs function and pass to

```
data: JSON.stringify({})
```

Comment: get all form data in an array and then pass it in this funciton

Comment: If i use ng-model="<?php echo //csrf token value?>" then it not showing any value but when I not use ng-model that time it shows  value. without ng-model I can't access that input value